# Python Selenium datepicker does not click and timeout

Tags: python, selenium, datepicker

I am trying to select the start date and end date of the website, and I tried:

```
driver.get('http://www.sse.com.cn/disclosure/bond/announcement/company/')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
datefield_st = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "start_date")))
datefield_st.click()
day=1
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//tr/td[text()='{}']".format(str(day))))).click()
datefield_ed = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "end_date")))
datefield_ed.click()
day_ed=1
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//tr/td[text()='{}']".format(str(day_ed))))).click()
driver.find_element_by_link_text("查询").click()
```

somehow the end date does not click,
' raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)

TimeoutException'

could someone help with this? Many thanks!

Comment: I can't offer a sufficient explanation as to why, but adjusting the selector to `wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f"//td[@class='day' and text()='{day_ed}']")))` worked for me. Seems Selenium doesn't recognise the new dates as clickable, but it recognises that they are there.

Comment: aybry it's the type of element they are. td vs a tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 4 elements with same xpath on page `"//tr/td[text()='1']"`
When you open second calendar, it finds the one from first calendar and tries to click on it but it can't cause it is closed.

First thing you need to do is to expand xpath to look only on calendar you need. e.g.
`(//div[@class='datetimepicker-days'])[1]` for first calendar, and `(//div[@class='datetimepicker-days'])[2]` for second

Second thing to be careful about is there are 2 occurrences of number 1 on each calendar (one for current one and one for next). If you look at html elements you can see that one for disabled next month has class 'new' in it so you need to expand xpath with e.g. `[not(contains(@class,'new'))]`

So your code should look like this

```
driver.get('http://www.sse.com.cn/disclosure/bond/announcement/company/')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
datefield_st = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "start_date")))
datefield_st.click()
day=1
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//div[@class='datetimepicker-days'])[1]//tr/td[text()='{}'][not(contains(@class,'new'))]".format(str(day))))).click()
datefield_ed = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "end_date")))
datefield_ed.click()
day_ed=1
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//div[@class='datetimepicker-days'])[2]//tr/td[text()='{}'][not(contains(@class,'new'))]".format(str(day_ed))))).click()
driver.find_element_by_link_text("查询").click()
```

Comment: Hi Ble, Thank you so much , the code works just fine! But may I ask why `@class,'datetimepicker'`, as I saw there are datetimepicker-mins/hour/day, should I specify it or the [1]and [2] may refer to mins or hour? not the start or end datepicker?

Comment: no problem :)
Great question! when you inspect html elements you can see that there is <div> element with class `datetimepicker datetimepicker-dropdown-bottom-right dropdown-menu`. Inside that div, there are 5 div elements on the same 'level' with classes `datetimepicker-minutes`, `datetimepicker-hours` etc.
All of them have `style="display: none;"` (you can't see them or click them) except `datetimepicker-days`.
I just gave you example of xpath. You can use whatever works for you.

Comment: Now that I checked it again, maybe the best one would be `(//div[@class='datetimepicker-days'])[1]//tr/td[text()='{}'][not(contains(@class,'new'))]` and `(//div[@class='datetimepicker-days'])[2]//tr/td[text()='{}'][not(contains(@class,'new'))]`
or `(//div[contains(@class,'datetimepicker-dropdown')])[1]//tr/td[text()='{}'][not(contains(@class,'new'))]` and `(//div[contains(@class,'datetimepicker-dropdown')])[2]//tr/td[text()='{}'][not(contains(@class,'new'))]`

Comment: I'll edit my answer because `//div[contains(@class,'datetimepicker')][2]` is not only the second calendar. There are 3 elements with that xpath. This code worked because it found  `//tr/td[text()='{}'][not(contains(@class,'new'))] ` inside of `(//div[contains(@class,'datetimepicker')][2])[2]` (second one)

Comment: Thank you so much for your elaborate explanation ble! I totally understand now, could you please help me with the month pick? I use`wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//div[@class,'datetimepicker-months'])[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/span[text()='{}']".format("一月")))).click()` but time out..

Comment: is that mean that when you choose like`datepicker-days` or`datepicker-months`, the others will be `display:none`(when you do not choose them)?

Comment: First change it to `//div[@class='datetimepicker-months']` or `//div[contains(@class,'datetimepicker-months'])`. When you want to get exact class name you use `=` and when you need part of it use `contains` and `,` . With the second one you can get e.g. dateti instead datetimepicker-months `//div[contains(@class,'dateti')]`. 
Little tip, when you inspect elements use ctrl+f on Elements tab (Elements, Console, Sources...) which opens search. There you can paste any xpath you want and it will show you if it exists (number on the right and 'paints' elements on the page in yellow (I use chrome).

Comment: When you search for `(//div[@class='datetimepicker-months'])[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/span[text()='一月']` it gives you 1 result but it won't show it on screen. And you CAN'T click on it. There is nothing you can do about it because of `style="display: none;"` which means it is not shown on screen. I don't know why the creators of the page left it in HTML. It was maybe a template so they only show elements they need.Try to double click on `style="display: none;"` in `<div class='datetimepicker-months' style="display: none;">` and change none to block. It will open another calendar below.

Comment: There is nothing you can to about it with selenium since it technically doesn't exist on page to click on. I guess you just wanted to ask why was it like that and you don't need that click?

Comment: If you need to select another month from this calendar, you would need to click on right arrow to switch

Comment: Thank you so much for your elaborate explanation! that really helps me to get some ideas from the web scrapping process, so nice of you, thanks! : )